# Node.js Express delete req.body not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express

```
router.delete('/board', function (req, res, next) {
var body = req.body;

if (!isEmpty(body)) {
    var index = findIndexInList(body);
    list.splice(index,1);
    res.sendStatus(200);
    return;
}
list=[];
res.sendStatus(200);
});



function findIndexInList(key) {

  for (var index in list) {
    var value = list[index];
    //value = { '{data:"2"}': '' } TypeOf = Object
    //key = { '{data:"2"}': '' } TypeOf = Object
    console.log(value === key); // why false? I think same so TRUE..
    if( value === key ) {
        return list.indexOf(value);
    }
}
return undefined;
}
```

Hello. Let me ask a few questions about req.body.
when I send data from client such as chrome console

```
(
$.ajax({
type: 'delete',
data : '{data:"2"}
});)
```

in server-side, LIST array have data. 
so I sent same data to server-side.

for example

```
list = [{ '{data:"1"}': '' },{ '{data:"2"}': '' } ];
//value = { '{data:"2"}': '' } Type = Object
//key = { '{data:"2"}': '' } Type = Object
console.log(value === key); // FALSE
```

why false? I think same object and data so TRUE..

Comment: Kindly update your question. Because you are asking for objects comparison but title is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `Objects` in javascript which is not possible this way. There is no good way to compare objects. However if your object is simple, with no methods then you can compare after converting it to json string

```
{} !== {}
key = { '{data:"2"}': '' }
value =  { '{data:"2"}': '' }
JSON.stringify(key)  === JSON.stringify(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

When javascript tests for object equalities, using double or triple eq, it will always check for internal references. [ref here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality)

Running this

```
var g = {some: 'thing'}
console.log({} == {});
console.log({a:1} == {a:1});
console.log({a:1} == {a:2});
console.log({} === {});
console.log(g === g);
console.log(g == g);
```

gives us

```
false
false
false
false
true
true
```

If you need to test equality of Object's contents, you should use something like this module https://github.com/substack/node-deep-equal

As you can see [here](https://github.com/substack/node-deep-equal/blob/master/test/cmp.js#L7) it is able to tell you if two differents objet instances have the same content or not.

you can also use the stringified tip as mentionned.